# PHP - twitch.tv CURL get page content

Tags: php, curl, get

I used PHP curl for getting page content from twitch.tv for some checks I was needed.
It seems twitch.tv done some changes and now no content is returning via PHP curl.

What I should done now to get content via php?

I used the following function on my script, but no response is returning...

```
   function get_web_page($url) {
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "test", // name of client
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,    // time-out on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
        ); 

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        $content  = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $content;
    }


// $url_final = something from twitch.tv

$response = get_web_page($url_final);  
echo $response;
```

Comment: "It seems twitch.tv done some changes". Have you looked at what they changed?

Comment: What url are you trying to fetch? I'm able to fetch it without any issues.

Comment: oh sorry for the incorrect description, I realized it better. Well, I need to return on $response, the full source code, twitch.tv page is returning. This means that I need also the code that loaded via javascript. I found about phantomjs, but as I undertand, it needs something special installation on the server? Any idea how to achieve the same, with the integrated functions of php? (to get also code that loaded via javascript). Regards!